# Dropdown lists selected item to Html button hyper links value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist and the Html hyperlink button.So i need when i select something in the dropdown list and then i click the button then Hyperlinks Quantity property fills with Dropdown list selected item value.

```
<div class="form-group col-6 mt-0 mt-lg-3 d-flex align-items-end">
    <select id="drpQuantity">
        <option value="0">--Select --</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <a href="@Url.Action("AddNewItems", "Home",
                new { ItemId = QitemId,
                      Quantity = //I need dropdown lists selected value here})">

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block rounded-pill" id="@QitemId" value="Add to Cart" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The view has already rendered so you cannot affect the `Quantity` value in Razor server-side code. You'll need to rewrite the href URL in JavaScript in response to the changed value event. Or, in a similar fashion, you'll intercept the link click and insert the quantity value before sending on to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jasen said before, `@Url.Action()` helper's `routeValues` parameters are rendered server-side before sending to browser and you can't change it directly with selected value from `<select>` element. You could use client-side code which provides additional query string parameter using selected value from `<select>` element, as provided in this example:

**Hyperlink example**

```html
<a id="link" href="#">Add New</a>
```

**Client-side manipulation**

```js
$('#drpQuantity').change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    // use prop function to set href attribute of target anchor link
    $('#link').prop('href', '@Url.Action("AddNewItems", "Home", new { ItemId = QitemId })' + '&Quantity=' + selected);
});
```

If you want to use plain/vanilla JS, you need to handle `onchange` event from `<select>` and set `href` attribute after getting anchor link ID/tag name:

```html
<select id="drpQuantity" onchange="setUrl(this)">...</select>

<script>
function setUrl(element) {
    var value = element.value;

    document.getElementById('link').href = '@Url.Action("AddNewItems", "Home", new { ItemId = QitemId })' + '&Quantity=' + selected;
}
</script>
```

The anchor link should be rendered like this example:

```
<a id="link" href="/Home/AddNewItems?ItemId=1&Quantity=1">Add New</a>
```

Live example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rVyFx1)